# Before insert trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to disable in before insert trigger inserting into table when some condition is true

```
 create or replace trigger CHECK_FOR_MAX_ENTRANTS
before insert on application
declare
    entrants_count number;
    max_entrants number;
begin
    select count(*) into entrants_count from application 
    where id_speciality = :new.id_speciality;

    select max_students_number into max_entrants from speciality s
    where s.id_speciality = :new.id_speciality;

    IF entrants_count >= max_entrants THEN
        **disable this insert**
end;
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that two concurrent transactions could insert the "last" allowed record because they can not see the other record yet.

Comment: Some other problems with this approach include:

Comment: PS.  I hit "Add Comment" too soon.  I was going to say...  Some other problems with this approach include:  a) What if max_entrants.max_students_number is updated to a smaller number?  What happens to the related rows in application if there are more than the max_students_number?  b) What if application.speciality is updated?  This could cause the count to exceed the related max_entrants.max_students_number.

Comment: To avoid these problems with a trigger-based approach, you might consider implementing this constraint using a materialized view instead.  You can find some examples at [link](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/enforcing-complex-constraints-in.html) and [link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:698031000346429496).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Oracle, then, in place of **disable this insert** you could:

```
IF entrants_count >= max_entrants THEN
    raise_application_error(-21010, 'Max number of Entrants Reached');
END IF;
```

See: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#sthref2006

**EDIT:**  It's generally a bad idea to have inserts fail silently (what you're asking for).  You also may run into mutating table errors if you try to delete the record in an after insert trigger.

Instead, just don't insert the record to begin with.
One way you could probably achieve this is to add something like this to the end of your insert statement:

```
WHERE EXISTS SELECT null FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) entrants_count FROM application 
WHERE id_speciality = :new.id_speciality) a,
(SELECT max_students_number max_entrants 
FROM speciality WHERE id_speciality = :new.id_speciality) s
WHERE a.entrants_count < s.max_entrants
```

This should only execute the insert statement when entrants_count < max_entrants (what you want).

Comment: i know that  i can throw an error, but i don't want to throw it, simply disable an insert operation, maybe it's better to use after insert trigger where simply delete newly inserted row if condition is true?

Answer (score 2):

Try raising an error:

```
IF entrants_count >= max_entrants THEN
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Cannot perform this insert!');
END IF;
```