# Automatically delete new records with specific values - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2000, dts

I have a table in a database (Oracle 11g) that receives roughly 45000 new records each day.  Our organization has roughly 15 items (is a predetermined be a static unique value for each) and I am looking to either delete these records automatically or change a specific value in the these records columns before my batch job packages these transactions and sends them off.  Any suggestions on the best way to do this?   These transactions are only 10-20 of the 45000 so checking each time they are entered seems like it may have to much cost.  To add the values come periodically through the day via DTS package from SQL 2000 server; and yes 2000 is end of life an we will be upgrading early next year.

Comment: How about using a before insert trigger. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

sample below - accept only +0 values, if a value is less than 0 we change it to 99999;

```
create table my_table (val int);

create or replace trigger my_trigger
  before insert on my_table  
  for each row
declare
begin  
    if :new.val <0  then:new.val := 99999; end if;
end my_trigger;

insert into my_table values(0);
insert into my_table values(1);
insert into my_table values(-1);

select * from my_table
1   0
2   1
3   99999
```

- if want to prevent insert of the "wrong" values - "silent insert reject" is not recommended, you'd better need either raise an exception in trigger or set a constraint, see discussion there: [Before insert trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310160/before-insert-trigger)

Comment: thank you.  Wouldn't the cost be fairly high for this given I only will have about ten instances per 45000?   On a side note this isn't a greater than/less than situation.  The values are specific 11 digit numbers that do not follow a pattern or range.

Comment: this is the nature of triggers, I don't think it will be a problem for dbms server exec one logic check. after 1st execute server should keep the source of trigger in memory, next check should be quick operation